# does the COLDFUSION BUILDER support coldfusion 8?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

I know ***coldfusion builder*** is released for developing coldfusion 9 applications. Now my question is whether ***coldfusion builder*** support ***COLDFUSION 8*** development?
Great thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can change the ColdFusion version for code assist, etc in the preferences.  Under ColdFusion > Editor Profiles > Editor > Code Assist.

The options are version 7 through 9.

Comment: With the update to ColdFusion Builder 2.0.1 options now include version 7 through 10. Plus you can make these settings at a project level.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure it supports it, in that you can write code that works just fine. In fact, I have used it to develop CF7 code - you just need to be aware that by default the hinting and helping mechanisms will probably target the features of 9 and you might get some errors from that. At least in CFEclipse you can change the version you are targetting - I would imagine CFBuilder allows for the same thing, but alas, I don't have it handy to hunt for the setting.

Give the demo a shot and see what you think.

Answer (score 0):

In case you work with visual studio code, it maybe is worth mentoning the newest version of the "coldfusion builder plugin" for visual studio code. It's free and from adobe and very useful. Just search for "ColdFusion" or "CFML" in your marketplace tab in VS Code. Also, there is a [pre-release document / whitepaper](https://cfdownload.adobe.com/pub/adobe/coldfusion/vscode/Beta_ColdFusion_extension_for_Visual_Studio_Code.pdf) about it.